# Problem displaying image on the movieclip

Tags: flash, loader, movieclip, addchild

Have little bit of problem for my flash apps

I have a loader which load the image from the server. I also have a large movieclip that hold a list of small movieclips that are used to preview an image using the loader class.

It can display the image if I used the loader to add it directly on the large movieclip but it doesn't display the image when add them to a small movieclip and add them to the large movieclip...

This is my code :

```
enter code heres    loaderinfo.loader.width *= scale;
                    loaderinfo.loader.height *= scale;

                var movie:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
                movie.image_src = xml.child("item")[loaderinfo.loader.name].child("image_src").valueOf();

                movie.x = 0;
                movie.y = 0;
                movie.width = loaderinfo.loader.width;
                movie.height = loaderinfo.loader.height;

                movie.addChild(loaderinfo.loader);
                ItemHolders.addChild(movie);

                col_count++;

                if (col_count == ttl_columms)
                {

                    distX = spacing;
                    distY += spacing + distHeight;
                }
                else if (col_count < ttl_columms)
                {
                    distX += spacing + distWidth;

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it could be due to this 3 lines of code:

```
movie.width = loaderinfo.loader.width;
movie.height = loaderinfo.loader.height;
movie.addChild(loaderinfo.loader);
```

You are trying to resize an empty MovieClip, and that could be problematic... try adding the child prior to resizing the movieclip (though I don't see the need for resizing it ;)).